# javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: "Envelope" doesnt contain ObjectFactory.class or jaxb.index

Tags: jaxb

Here xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:com="com.myproject.server.services.ws.cfg.face">
    <soap:Header />
    <soap:Body>
        <com:modifyNetwork>
            <Network xmlns="urn:com.myproject.server.ws.dto.cfg">
                <supportedFeatures>
                    <nmsDiversity>ENABLE</nmsDiversity>
                    <fullSiteDiversity>ENABLE</fullSiteDiversity>
                </supportedFeatures>
                <fullSiteDiversity>
                    <activeDc>DC2</activeDc>
                </fullSiteDiversity>
            </Network>
        </com:modifyNetwork>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Here my pojo:

```
import javax.validation.Valid;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "Network", namespace = "urn:com.myproject.ngnms.server.ws.dto.cfg")
@XmlType(name = "Network", namespace = "urn:com.myproject.server.ws.dto.cfg")
public class Network {
    @NotNull
    @Valid
    private NetworkSupportedFeaturesSection supportedFeatures;

    @Valid
    private NetworkFullSiteDiversitySection fullSiteDiversity;
}
```

So I need to unmarshall only subelement **Network**

So I skip parent elements like this:

```
 private static Optional<Network> convertXMLToObject(URL url) {
        try {
            JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance("Envelope:Body:modifyNetwork"); // error here
            Unmarshaller un = context.createUnmarshaller();
            return Optional.of((Network) un.unmarshal(url)); 
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            LOGGER.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        return Optional.empty();
    }
```

And here unit test:

```
 @Test
    public void should_throw_exception_with_error_message_when_execute_operation_with_corrupted_parameter2() throws IOException {
        URL url = getClass().getResource("/modify_request.xml");
        Optional<Network> network = convertXMLToObject(url);
        assertTrue(network.isPresent());
    }
```

But I get error:

```
javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Provider com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory could not be instantiated: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: "Envelope" doesnt contain ObjectFactory.class or jaxb.index
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:146) ~[?:1.8.0_342]
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:335) ~[?:1.8.0_342]
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:431) ~[?:1.8.0_342]
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:394) ~[?:1.8.0_342]
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:298) ~[?:1.8.0_342]
    at com.myproject.integrationtest.server.ws.NetworkWebServiceTest.convertXMLToObject(NetworkWebServiceTest.java:104) ~[test-classes/:?]
    at com.myproject.integrationtest.server.ws.NetworkWebServiceTest.should_throw_exception_with_error_message_when_execute_operation_with_corrupted_parameter2(NetworkWebServiceTest.java:98) ~[test-classes/:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_342]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_342]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_342]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_342]
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59) ~[junit-4.13.2.jar:4.13.2]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12) ~[junit-4.13.2.jar:4.13.2]
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56) ~[junit-4.13.2.jar:4.13.2]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17) ~[junit-4.13.2.jar:4.13.2]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26) ~[junit-4.13.2.jar:4.13.2]
    at org.junit.rules.TestWatcher$1.evaluate(TestWatcher.java:61) ~[junit-4.13.2.jar:4.13.2]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306) ~[junit-4.13.2.jar:4.13.2]
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.evaluate(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:100) ~[junit-4.13.2.jar:4.13.2]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:366) ~[junit-4.13.2.jar:4.13.2]
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:103) ~[junit-4.13.2.jar:4.13.2]
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:63) ~[junit-4.13.2.jar:4.13.2]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331) ~[junit-4.13.2.jar:4.13.2]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79) ~[junit-4.13.2.jar:4.13.2]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329) ~[junit-4.13.2.jar:4.13.2]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66) ~[junit-4.13.2.jar:4.13.2]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293) ~[junit-4.13.2.jar:4.13.2]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306) ~[junit-4.13.2.jar:4.13.2]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413) ~[junit-4.13.2.jar:4.13.2]
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137) ~[junit-4.13.2.jar:4.13.2]
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69) ~[junit-rt.jar:?]
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38) ~[junit-rt.jar:?]
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11) ~[idea_rt.jar:?]
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35) ~[junit-rt.jar:?]
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:232) ~[junit-rt.jar:?]
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:55) ~[junit-rt.jar:?]
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: "Envelope" doesnt contain ObjectFactory.class or jaxb.index
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:263) ~[jaxb-runtime-2.3.5.jar:2.3.5]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_342]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_342]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_342]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_342]
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:171) ~[?:1.8.0_342]
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:131) ~[?:1.8.0_342]
```